# How to get response of serverResponse in NestJS

Tags: express, nestjs, middleware

When i create Logger middleware with Nestjs I want logger response || data of server send for client but in Response from express but it not found option

```
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express';
@Injectable()
export class EcomWebLogerMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
 private logger = new Logger();
 use(request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction): void {
  const { method, url: path, query, params, body } = request;
  this.logger.log(
  ` ${method} ${path} query: ${JSON.stringify(
    query
  )} params: ${JSON.stringify(params)} body: ${JSON.stringify(body)}`,
  'FE Request'
 );
 response.on('close', () => {
  const { statusCode } = response;
  // i want get data in response:Response from express
  this.logger.log(`${method} ${statusCode} ${path}  `, 'FE Response');
  });
 next();
 }
}
```

With ExceptionFilter you can use ArgumentsHost after you can use it to getResponse

```
@Catch(HttpException)
export class HttpExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
 constructor(private readonly responseUtils: ResponseUtils) {}
 catch(exception: HttpException, host: ArgumentsHost) {
 const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
 const res = ctx.getResponse<Response>();
 const status = exception.getStatus();
 const response: any = exception.getResponse();
 // this is response i want get
... }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to implement with an [interceptor](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors). It is very similar to koa's middleware.

Comment: Use it have abatement performance of app ? i think interceptor cover my controller so i readed another blog and advice is not should use it similar the middleware

Comment: If you insist on implementing it with express middleware. You need to rewrite `response.write` and `response.end`. [How to log the response body with express](https://thewebdev.info/2022/03/06/how-to-log-the-response-body-with-express/)

Answer (score 0):

can you show your package.json, try install **"@types/express"** dependency